# Selenium "ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED"

Tags: python, selenium

Trying to use proxies with selenium, it worked succesfully before but now even if I try different proxies which appear to be working fine according to proxy checkers online, I keep getting the error `ERR_TUNNEL_CONNECTION_FAILED` within the chrome instance.

Code:

```
PROXY ="176.9.119.170:3128"
print(PROXY)
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % PROXY)
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
chrome.get("http://whatismyipaddress.com")
time.sleep(3)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE SOLVED:
When inputting your proxy, make sure the proxy is working especially since public free proxies could stop working at any moment, also make sure to specify which type of proxy your are using within the argument.
eg.

```
chrome_options.add_argument('--proxy-server='"socks4://"+PROXY)
```